# How to highlight text on screen (OS level)

Tags: python, windows, automation, macros

Is it possible to hightligh a string or a particular word or set of words whenever they appear on screen? Not necessarily on the web, but on OS level. This can be on desktop, inside a folder, etc.

For example, I want to highlight this text: "I like baking pies".

When said text appears on screen, be it browser or desktop, I want it to be highlighted.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use OCR (Optical Character Recognition), something like pytesseract.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking of this, but I'm running another script at the same time, and this will drain all my resources. Is there a software where I can input the text and it automatically highlights it whenever it appears?

Comment: In general, OS windows are bitmaps.  To "scrape" a window you must grab the bits and do OCR.  You can possibly use accessibility functions in some cases, but that is only if the app has implemented the code to support them.

Comment: Is there a practical way of doing this?

Comment: You could look at the open-source NVDA screen reader to see what it does.  It's C++ not python though.

Comment: Or if you need to use Python, then i would recommend EasyOCR which is gpu and not cpu based, like tesseract.

Comment: The NVDA screen reader looks like a Wish version of Nuance Dragon. Does it only read text?

Comment: Wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NonVisual_Desktop_Access